# from http to Http Client, cant get my object to become a string array

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I am new to angular, and this may be a dumb question but I am on this for some time now and can't find out how to fix it. 
I am following this tutorial

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1245243/How-to-Create-an-App-with-Angular-and-ASP-NET-C

but now http has been deprecated and Angular now uses Http Client:

I keep getting an error here

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'BackEnd';
  public values: string[];


 constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('/api/values').subscribe(result => {
      this.values = result.json() as string[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

I understand you cant use json() on an object type , which is what subscribe returns but , this is a project integration with .net core 2.1 and I need to send data to my controller and in the tutorial the format of the data is string array so I tried the following:

```
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/api/values').subscribe(result => {
      this.values = this.values.push(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

since values is string array I thought I could just push, with a conversion to string, also tried String(result), but then gives me another error "type number is not assignable to string[]"
... 
I am really confused on how to possible fix this, but I need to have this working in this particular way to fully integrate asp net core2 with angular6.

(yes I know you can create the project from scratch on visual studio but I was asked to add an angular project to a particular .net core project already existing)

By the way, this works for example :

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.values = ["THIS IS A DUMB STATIC TEST", "ALSO THIS NEEDS TO BE AN ARRAY FOR THIS TEST SO HERE IT IS"];

Because here it is indeed a string array

Comment: ...What's the error? Are you sure `result` isn't already a string array?

Comment: @HereticMonkey if I make " constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/api/values').subscribe(result => {
      this.values = result; " the error is that type object is not assignable to type string[] which means result is type object and  I need it to be type string[]

Comment: So, debugging JS 101: use `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` and see what the result is.

Comment: it doesn't log anything because of the project not being solely in angular

Comment: If it's a web page running in a browser, that should work if `console.error(error)` works...

Comment: If you read the documentation, you will find a solution :) https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response